# gridview paging inside the list view in aspx

Tags: asp.net, listview, gridview

is it possible to have grid view pagging function inside a list view in asp.net.
i have two column subject and lesson.
i have more than 30 subjects and each subject contains more than 100 lesson.

i want to load the subject list and as soon as i click on any subject the lesson belong to each subject show.
as of now 100 subjects are showing, is it possible that i can have a pagging so that i can see 20 20 subject in each layout while not uploading/refreshing the whole webpage.

you can see the live page where i want to do it at

http://gvapps.zapto.org:801/studywiser/home.aspx

is there any way possible that grid view pagging works inside the list view.

though i am not the programmer i am writing this question on behalf of my programmer who is telling me its not possible to have it.

any suggestion or answer will be highly appreciated.

thank you
yasir

Comment: Can you upload any image of what exactly you want to achieve as compared to what you already have. The Link isn't opening at my end

Comment: thank you so much but i need damm 10 reputation to upload the image

Comment: Upload it somewhere else and post the link then